# Python SQlite3 insert with params

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

**Problem:**

I have a problem with inserting data into SQlite with python. At this moment i am new to python so this must be beginner mistake.

**Errors :**

> OperationalError: unrecognized token: "{"

**What I have tried:**

I have read many tutorials and tried many options as shown below in the code examples.But i cannot get this to work without error for some reason.

Some examples :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wanted_movie (tmdb_id, name, year) VALUES ({tmdb_id}, {name}, {year})".format(
        tmdb_id=str(data['id']), name=str(data['title']), year=str(data['release_date']).split('-')[0]))

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wanted_movie (tmdb_id, name, year) VALUES ({tmdb_id}, {name}, {year})", {
        "tmdb_id": str(data['id']), "name": str(data['title']), "year": str(data['release_date']).split('-')[0]})
    conn.commit()
```

**Question :**

Can someone help me to insert a row correctly with SQlite3 in a pythonic way?

Comment: The specific error is missing the `**` to unpack the dictionary in the second example. However, please read https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html and **don't** use `str.format` to interpolate variables!

Comment: I read about 10 tutorials, but not the docs. Thanks

Comment: Add as answer please. So i can accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than a pythonic way there is a sqlitic way

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html)

> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put **?** as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s [`execute()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method.

One of your examples can be solved by using

```
values = (data['id'],data['title'],data['release_date'])
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wanted_movie (tmdb_id, name, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",values)
```

Comment: As the Python Database API Specification v2.0 mentions, the `?` placeholder can also be found out from the module's [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) global, i.e. `sqlite3.paramstyle` is `'qmark'`.